# Magento 1.9.2.4 PayPal order telephone number missing

Tags: magento-1.9

I have noticed that whenever a customer places an order with PayPal their telephone number does not appear in their order details. Also their name is blank in the Last 5 Orders in the dashboard?

Comment: Please try to debug & check first it's storing in Database or not & you can see on My Account or not?

Comment: I just edited the question because I noticed it is only happening with PayPal orders

Comment: I have had a look at the sales_order_flat_address table and it does not appear in there either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you turn on phone numbers required in your PayPal account, as without this PayPal won't share the phone numbers anymore. For most customers PayPal already has their phone number on file so it won't reduce conversions as they say it might.

Instructions:

1. Log in to your PayPal account at https://www.paypal.com. Click the
   Profile subtab, click "profile & Settings" The Profile Summary page
   appears.
2. In the Selling Tools column, click the Website Preferences
   link. Scroll down the page to the Contact Telephone Number section.
3. Change  this to: "On (Required Field)"
4. Scroll to the bottom of the page and click the Save button.